# How to label values from a data dictionary in R

Tags: r, r-labelled, labelled

I have two files, one of which being a .csv file and the other an Excel document with a data dictionary in it. I want to label the values of the .csv file with the values from the data dictionary, so that the data frame looks like one loaded from a .dta/.sav file (in that the cells don't contain the values as a character/factor, but a labelled value).
**Is there a way of assigning value labels to cells from a  data dictionary?"**

Dummy data are below. I did work out how to do it using `match_df` from `{matchmaker}`, but this put all the values in as character rather than labelling them.

```
# where dd is the data dictionary and df the data frame
dd <- data.frame(variable.name = c(rep("sex", 2), 
                                   rep("age", 1), 
                                   rep("school", 3), 
                                   rep("parent", 2)), 
                 value = c(1, 2, 
                           -96, 
                           1, 2, -96, 
                           1, 2), 
                 variable.label = c("male", "female", 
                                    NA, 
                                    "private", "state", "missing", 
                                    "mother", "father"))


df <- data.frame(id = 1:10, 
                 sex = rep(c(1, 2), 5), 
                 age = c(rep(5, 9), -96), 
                 school = as.integer(c(rep(c(1, 2, 3), 3), 1)),
                 parent = c(rep(1, 2), rep(2, 8)))

# the following works to an extent, but it's not the desired outcome:
match_df(df, 
         dictionary = dd, 
         from = "value", 
         to = "variable.label",
         by = "variable.name")

# desired outcome would look something like this:
 dput()
structure(list(id = 1:10, sex = structure(c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
1, 2, 1, 2), labels = c(male = 1, female = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double")), age = structure(c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, -96), labels = c(missing = -96), class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double")), school = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), labels = structure(1:3, names = c("private", 
"state", "missing")), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
"integer")), parent = structure(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2), labels = c(mother = 1, father = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double"))), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: would you be ok with turning the numeric variables to factors or does it have to stay as a numeric variable

Comment: The numbers need to stay as numbers... It essentially needs to look as though it's been loaded from a .dta file so the values show as numeric with meta-data attached to them. The class of them would formally be something like "haven_labelled" "vctrs_vctr"     "double".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the first thing to do is `split(dd)` into a list of data frames, each of which contains the appropriate factor levels for one column.

```r
levels_list <- split(dd, ~variable.name)

# This looks like:
# $age
#   variable.name value variable.label
# 3           age   -96           <NA>

# $parent
#   variable.name value variable.label
# 7        parent     1         mother
# 8        parent     2         father
# <etc>
```

You can then write a function to construct the `haven_labelled` class which takes one of these data frames and `df` and returns a labelled vector.

```r
create_haven_labelled <- function(col, dat = df, ldf = levels_list[[col]]) {
    levels <- unique(dat[[col]])
    labels <- ldf[, "variable.label"]

    if (all(is.na(labels))) {
        # Assume no labels if none except NA provided
        levels <- ldf[, "value"]
        labels <- "missing"
    } else { 
        # Add "missing" to labels not found
        labels <- labels[match(levels, ldf$value)]
        labels[is.na(labels)] <- "missing"
    }

    dat[[col]] |>
        haven::labelled() |>
        `attr<-`("labels", setNames(levels, labels))
}
```

This function labels any values not found as `"missing"`, except in the case where there are no labels other than missing values provided, e.g. `"age"`, where it assumes that no labels except `"missing"` are required.

We can then apply this to the relevant columns:

```r
out_df <- dplyr::as_tibble(df) # just so it prints nicely
out_df[names(levels_list)] <- lapply(names(levels_list), create_haven_labelled)

out_df
# # A tibble: 10 × 5
#       id sex        age           school      parent    
#    <int> <dbl+lbl>  <dbl+lbl>     <int+lbl>   <dbl+lbl> 
#  1     1 1 [male]     5           1 [private] 1 [mother]
#  2     2 2 [female]   5           2 [state]   1 [mother]
#  3     3 1 [male]     5           3 [missing] 2 [father]
#  4     4 2 [female]   5           1 [private] 2 [father]
#  5     5 1 [male]     5           2 [state]   2 [father]
#  6     6 2 [female]   5           3 [missing] 2 [father]
#  7     7 1 [male]     5           1 [private] 2 [father]
#  8     8 2 [female]   5           2 [state]   2 [father]
#  9     9 1 [male]     5           3 [missing] 2 [father]
# 10    10 2 [female] -96 [missing] 1 [private] 2 [father]

identical(out_df, desired) # TRUE
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the reason for the error there is no label for school == 3 in dd dataset. instead -96 was used.

I usually prefer, "long format-> left join -> wide format" approach.

```r
        dd <- data.frame(variable.name = c(rep("sex", 2), 
                                           rep("age", 1), 
                                           rep("school", 3), 
                                           rep("parent", 2)), 
                         value = c(1, 2, 
                                   -96, 
                                   1, 2, -96, 
                                   1, 2), 
                         variable.label = c("male", "female", 
                                            NA, 
                                            "private", "state", "missing", 
                                            "mother", "father"))
        
        
        df <- data.frame(id = 1:10, 
                         sex = rep(c(1, 2), 5), 
                         age = c(rep(5, 9), -96), 
                         school = as.integer(c(rep(c(1, 2, 3), 3), 1)),
                         parent = c(rep(1, 2), rep(2, 8)))
        
   
        library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
        library(tidyr)
        
        df |> 
                mutate(school = if_else(school == 3, -96, school)) |>  # Ignore if 3 should be stay as 3
                mutate(across(everything(), ~as.character(.))) |> 
                pivot_longer(
                        -id,
                        names_to = "names",
                        values_to = "values"
                        ) |> 
                left_join(dd |> 
                                  mutate(value = as.character(value)), 
                          by = c("names" = "variable.name", "values" = "value")) |> 
                mutate(new = if_else((names == "age" & values != "-96"), values, variable.label)) |> 
                select(id, names, new) |>  
                pivot_wider(
                        names_from = "names",
                        values_from = "new"
                        )
#> # A tibble: 10 × 5
#>    id    sex    age   school  parent
#>    <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>   <chr> 
#>  1 1     male   5     private mother
#>  2 2     female 5     state   mother
#>  3 3     male   5     missing father
#>  4 4     female 5     private father
#>  5 5     male   5     state   father
#>  6 6     female 5     missing father
#>  7 7     male   5     private father
#>  8 8     female 5     state   father
#>  9 9     male   5     missing father
#> 10 10    female <NA>  private father
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the 3 vs. -96 wasn't the problem I'm having. I kind of wanted values to be ignored/left as is if they're not in the data dictionary. I want the values to be put into the dataset as labelled variables (i.e., the format they'd be in if the data were imported from SPSS/Stata) rather than a character/factor variable.